# automount doesn't work in linux mint after upgrade to rafaela

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, automounting, file-manager

I recently upgraded my mint, I'm using 64bit version on cinnamon.

The problem is that ntfs partitions in the hard drive and flash drives and android attached phone don't show automatically in the file manager, I didn't have this problem before nor I have in my other computer which has xfce(and different hardware).

I can mount most of these normally from terminal or from Preferences->Disks but they don't show automatically and I checked from disks that automount is ON.

I plugged my flash drive and typed dmesg right after that, here is the output related to the flash drive :

```
[ 1739.280020] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1739.414603] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1516, idProduct=1603
[ 1739.414610] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1739.414614] usb 1-3: Product: USB_DRIVE
[ 1739.414618] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: 
[ 1739.414622] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 2008111700000000000044DA
[ 1739.476896] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1739.477074] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 1739.477767] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1739.485916] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 1740.476773] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB_DRIVE        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1740.477483] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1740.478117] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 15945728 512-byte logical blocks: (8.16 GB/7.60 GiB)
[ 1740.480436] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1740.480447] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 1740.484554] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1740.484566] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1741.095171]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1741.097751] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

it seems detected, it's just not automounted and not shown in Nemo.

and here is the output of sudo fdisk -l :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500106780160 bytes
240 heads, 63 sectors/track, 64601 cylinders, total 976771055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe8dffe92

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2   *        2046   165919319    82958637    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       165919320   976768064   405424372+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5        81931563   165919319    41993878+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6            2048     9764863     4881408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7         9766912    11522047      877568   83  Linux
/dev/sda8        11524096    40818687    14647296   83  Linux
/dev/sda9        40820736    81930239    20554752   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 8164 MB, 8164212736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 992 cylinders, total 15945728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1    15945727     7972863+  ee  GPT
```

there doesn't seem to be any problem from the output, all partitions are detected, sda would be my hard drive and sdb is the flash drive(I ran fdisk while it's attached).

last but not least, I recently replaced my motherboard and upgraded the RAMS to DDR3 , I don't recall if I did that before or after I upgraded my mint and I don't know if that's a problem, anyway here is my hardware just in case :

```
System:    Host: abd-G31M-S2L Kernel: 3.19.0-26-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 2.6.13  Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Machine:   Mobo: Gigabyte model: G41M-Combo version: x.x Bios: Award version: F3 date: 06/09/2010
CPU:       Dual core Intel Pentium D CPU (-MCP-) clocked at 2400.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G86 [GeForce 9400 GT]
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1280x1024@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 9400 GT/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.76
Network:   Card: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 508.3GB (2.6% used) 1: model: WDC_WD5000AAKS
           2: model: USB_DRIVE
Info:      Processes: 138 Uptime: 43 min Memory: 652.4/3951.3MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 1.9.17
```

So what to do to solve this problem ?